# Can't position background image in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, background-image

I have the following code in my CSS:

```css
#photos {
   width:340px;
   height:250px;
   background-image: url('../images/photosBoxIcon.png'); 
   background-position: top 20px right 20px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-color:#211f1f;
   border: 1px solid #666666;
   float:left;
   margin-top:20px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;  
}
```

While this code successfully positions my background icon in Firefox and Opera, Chrome and  Safari position the icon in the top left corner.

When inspecting the code in chrome, I can see the line `background-position: top 20px right 20px;` crossed and with a warning mark on the beginning on the line, which means that Chrome consider this code incorrect. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Is four values for background-position is allowed???

Answer (score 0):

use either

```
background-position: top right;
```

or

```
background-position:20px 20px;
```

and you can also use shorthand like :

```
background:#211f1f url('../images/photosBoxIcon.png') 20px 20px no-repeat;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```
"background-position: top 20px right 20px;"
```

its not a proper syntax may be that's why chrome not displaying result properly

Comment: "right 20px top 20px" is correct syntax for css3. See w3c: http://w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position Also see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57963 for possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
background-position: top right 20px 20px;
```

Comment: no, this will not work - especially for Chrome/Safari